# Using 2 Vendors and Splitting Shipments

Tags: multi-vendor, order-splitting, dropshipping

We are currently connected to our vendor/warehouse using ShipStation. We need to also connect to a totally different vendor/warehouse using Shipworks.

How do we integrate both and also have Magento use both together?

If someone orders Product A, the order is sent to ShipStation. 
If someone orders Product B, the order is sent to ShipWorks.

If someone orders Product A & Product B, the order is split and Product A gets sent to ShipStation and Product B gets sent to ShipWorks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order splitting is an important part of any multi vendor magento marketplace. But unfortunately, it is as difficult to achieve as it is important.

It involves creating a special attribute called “Seller Attribute” in Magento. This attribute decides seller role and assigns a Unique ID to them.

Once the “Seller Attribute” is assigned user proceeds to add their products on the website. Here, each Seller Attribute is linked to the Product ID and this is the base of splitting payments in a Magento Multivendor Marketplace extension.